# Google Cloud Platform pub/sub - messages aren't being being delivered to subscriber

Tags: node.js, email, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am setting up push notifications for gmail based on the guide provided by google (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push).  I want to have my node app register a client with .watch(), and then receive emails at a specified endpoint, as described in the documentation.

I have created the pub/sub topic, added gmail as a publisher, added a subscriber, and called watch() in my node app.  watch() returns the appropriate { historyId: xxxx, expiration: yyyy } object which, according to google's documentation, means the call succeeded.

handler for receiving email notification on backend:

```
export const receiveGmailEmail: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
  log('Received update from google!');
  log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));
  return res.status(200);
}
```

Registering:

```
  const watchRes = await gmailClient.watch();
  log('====> Watch Response <=====');
  log(JSON.stringify(watchRes, null, 2));
```

Server log that shows it is registering properly:
====> Watch Response <=====
{
  "historyId": "6560",
  "expiration": "1562025255689"
}

I never receive messages at the receive endpoint on my node app. According to the server logs, I never actually receive any request when a message is published.  The problem appears to be that my messages are undelivered.  I have confirmed through the Stackdriver monitor that the pub/sub topic is publishing messages when I send an email to the email address, but if I view the details of the subscription in Stackdriver, it shows an increasing number of undelivered messages.

Any thoughts on why messages in a subscription are sitting around undelivered?

Comment: Is the Pub/Sub subscription you configured during this step a pull subscription or a push subscription? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#create_a_subscription

Can you check the subscription/pull_request_count and subscription/push_request_count metrics in Stackdriver? What response_codes are being recorded?

Comment: Hi Lauren! 
The subscription is set up as a push subscription
The push_request_count metric is 1, and the response_class is remote_server_4xx and the response_code is 403 (Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't see it before!).  Looking through the google docs, I think this means there's a permissions issue (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/error-codes).  I've verified that I have added a service account as a subscriber and gmail as the publisher in my topic.  Is there something I need to do to tie the service account with my app besides just passing the topic name to watch?

Comment: What endpoint is Pub/Sub pushing to? I am asking how you are mapping `receiveGmailEmail` to an HTTP endpoint that Pub/Sub is calling via HTTP Post.

Comment: @Lauren, sorry, just realized I forgot to tag you in that previous comment!

Comment: @JohnHanley, the route mapping on the node server is done in another file:

const router = Router();
...
const post = router.post.bind(router);
...
post('/emails/gmail/receive', receiveGmailEmail);

But I think it's not even hitting my server because I don't see anything in my server logs on AWS.  I would expect to at least see an incoming request that hit the server, even if I don't have a route to handle it

Comment: Show all your code instead of us trying to guess. The first rule of StackOverflow, your code must be self contained so that your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: @JohnHanley, as I stated in the question, "According to the server logs, I never actually receive any request when a message is published." This means my server isn't receiving any request from Google's pub/sub at any endpoint, so I decided to leave off the bits of code that aren't relevant to the problem I'm currently facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this wasn't a Google pub/sub issue.  Amazon Cloudfront blocks POST requests by default, so I had to edit the caching behavior to enable POST requests.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesAllowedHTTPMethods